ZonedDateTime with incorrect timezone fetched from database
I have an entity called "Turno" that has an attribute ZonedDateTime.
   @Column(name = "fecha", nullable = false)
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private ZonedDateTime fechaTurno;

When saving this entity, I have no problem because the value and time zone are stored correctly in PostgreSQL. The problem is that when retrieving rows from the backend, the time zone is converted to UTC.
Here you can see how the date is stored (correctly)

And then, when I fetch this rows the timezone is "UTC"

I already configured my project with these lines
Application.properties
spring.jackson.time-zone=America/Argentina/Buenos_Aires
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.time_zone=America/Argentina/Buenos_Aires

main.java

@PostConstruct
public void init(){
    TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/Argentina/Buenos_Aires"));
}


I need to retrieve the date with the correct time zone (GMT-03). Or I have to explicitly modify every time I fetch this date

What's the column type definition in the database?

@aled From the image it is timestamp with time zone.

I believe that your surprising result is documented. From the PostgreSQL docs: For timestamp with time zone, the internally stored value is always in UTC … So why did PostgreSQL show -03 as “time zone”? I don’t know. My guess is it is applying your default time zone. What happens if you store and retrieve values in other time zones? It seems that you will need to convert to America/Argentina/Buenos_Aires yourself after retrieval.

(It’s the case for many database engines that “timestamp with time zone” really promises too much and only gives you “timestamp with UTC time zone”.)

I believe that common usage is: -03 or -03:00 is a UTC offset. America/Argentina/Buenos_Aires is a time zone. A time zone is an area that shares the same time and comprises the past and known future UTC offsets in that area. Buenos Aires had summer time (DST) until 2000 and again from 2007 to 2009 and hence was at UTC offset -2 during summer.

Explain your screenshots and examples. Is the first screenshot from a database tool like pgAdmin? The second screenshot shows a ZonedDateTime object, but how was that object instantiated?

tl;dr

entity called "Turno" that has an attribute ZonedDateTime.

Wrong class. Use OffsetDateTime for TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE SQL type.
Example data is sensible
Regarding your example data, 2024-05-27 09:00:00-03 is the same moment as 2024-05-27T12:00Z. The -03 means three hours behind UTC. The Z is short for “offset from UTC of zero hours-minutes-seconds”. At that moment, the Argentina/Buenos_Aires was using an offset of three hours before UTC. So 9 AM in that zone is the same as noon in UTC, offset by negative three hours.
In other words, 2024-05-27 09:00:00-03 & 2024-05-27T12:00Z are two ways of looking at one single point on the timeline.
JDBC maps to OffsetDateTime
ZonedDateTime is not mapped to a SQL type in JDBC.
That lack is because the SQL standard recognizes only offset-from-UTC, not time zone. The types defined in the standard, TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE and TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE are misnomers; the standard authors meant offset-from-UTC. (Just one of many quirks is the SQL standard.)
Offset versus Zone
What is the difference between offset and zone? An offset is merely a number of hours-minutes-seconds ahead or behind the temporal meridian of UTC. A time zone is much more. A time zone is a named history of the past, present, and future changes to the offset used by the people of a particular region as decided by their politicians.
For exchanging with a database column of a type akin to  the SQL standard type TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE use only OffsetDateTime class in Java.
In straight JDBC:
OffsetDateTime odt = myResultSet.getObject( … , OffsetDateTime.class ) ;

… and:
myPreparedStatement.setObject( … , odt ) ;

Apply your desired time zone.
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "xx" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = odt.at

Postgres stores in UTC (offset of zero)
Furthermore, understand that Postgres always stores TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE values with an offset from UTC of zero hours-minutes-seconds — always. Any offset or zone supplied with an input is used to adjust the date & time to UTC. Any value retrieved is always in UTC — always.
After using any supplied offset or zone to adjust to UTC, Postgres discards that offset/zone. All that remains is a date and time as seen from an offset of zero.
So this is yet another reason you cannot use ZonedDateTime with your TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE column: There is  no known time zone to be applied to the retrieved UTC value.
Spring
Apparently Spring can dynamically apply a specific time zone to the UTC value retrieved from Postgres. I do not really know, as I do not use Spring. But that is what I gather from the info you provided.
Personally, I would rather retrieve the exact value from the database, then massage the data afterwards. But reasonable people may disagree.
Beware middleware
You said:

Here you can see how the date is stored (correctly)

No, not correct. If what you show in that screenshot is from a database tool such as pgAdmin, that tool is lying to you.
Postgres stores TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE values only with an offset of zero. So the displayed offset of three hours (-03) behind UTC is not really true.
Unfortunately, some tools and middleware choose to dynamically apply some default time zone to the TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE value stored in UTC. This anti-feature creates the illusion of a time zone having been stored.
When using such tools with this misguided anti-feature, I suggest setting its default time zone to UTC for an offset of zero. That may be a session setting, but depends on the tool.

This is incredibly useful and comprehensive information. Cheers!
